# What is wrong in the following code for CodeChef May Long Challenge, Chef and Strange Matrix?

Tags: c

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int n, m, p, i, j, total_cost, cost;
    scanf("%lld %lld %lld", &n, &m, &p);
    long long int ar[n][m];
    for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= m; ++j)
        {
            ar[i][j] = j;
        }
    }
    while(p--)
    {
        scanf("%lld %lld", &i, &j);
        ar[i][j] += 1;
    }

    /*
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= m; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ", ar[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    */

    if(n == 1 && m == 1)
    {
        printf("0\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(m == 1)
    {
        for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        {
            printf("0\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        total_cost = 0, cost = 0;
        for(j = m; j >= 2; --j)
        {
            cost = ar[i][j] - ar[i][j - 1];
            if( cost < 0 )
            {
                printf("-1\n");
                break;
            }
            total_cost += cost;
        }
        if(cost >= 0)
        {
            printf("%lld\n", total_cost);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is giving me WA. Here is the problem description [CHEFBM](http://www.codechef.com/MAY14/problems/CHEFBM).

Test cases I have checked:

```
1. 1 5 3
1 2
1 4
1 5
```

#### Output

```
5
 2. 4 4 6
2 2
3 2
3 2
4 3
4 4
4 3
```

#### Output

```
3
3
-1
4
 3. 1 4 5
1 3
1 2
1 2
1 1
1 1
```

#### Output

```
1
 4. 4 4 6
3 2
2 3
3 2
2 4
1 2
3 2
```

#### Output

```
3
4
3
3
 5. 4 1 1
1 1
```

#### Output

```
0
0
0
0
 6. 1 4 3
1 1
1 1
1 4
```

#### Output

```
-1
 7. 1 1 1
1 1
```

#### Output

```
0
 8. 1 1 2
1 1
1 1
```

#### Output

```
0
 9. 2 2 3
1 1
1 1
1 1
```

#### Output

```
-1
1
```

And many more. For which test case is this giving wrong answer?

Comment: Array indexes in C starts from zero and go up to DIMENSION-1. You apparently suppose them to be in range 1 to DIMENSION.

Comment: What can be the consequences? I am running this on Linux, gcc 4.3.3 and it is running fine. I ran this on online compilers, and it is running fine.

Comment: The consequences are undefined behavior, which means anything can happen, including appearing to work correctly sometimes.

Comment: Oh really. Thanks.
Is this same with C++?

Comment: It would be really helpful, if I can know the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @TapasweniPathak I think because your question is trivial. The case that indexes of arrays start with 0 and go up to `dim - 1`, as Marian has already written, should be known. So, some basic tutorials should have solved your problem easily.

Comment: No it's not solving the problem.

Comment: "Discussing CodeChef’s problems or any aspect of problem, on any other platform on web, on identification, could lead to disabling of respective account and banning from the community."

Answer (score 2):

As given in the constraints, n and m both can be 10^5. Allocating a 2-d array a[10^5][10^5], is not feasible here. You are running out of memory and hence you might be getting *Run time error* or *Wrong answer*. Your algorithm is O(n^2) so it will not pass in the given time limit. Try to optimize your code.

For further assistance, you can check [my code](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/3870197).